# Angular CLI ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm converting a project to use angular cli and everything is working (once it's build) but i've got a weird behaviour during build.

with `ng serve`
I always get this error the first time I try: ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null

with `ng build` throws the same error

but if I use `ng build --watch`
and after the first build fails and I edit a file to trigger the build again it will succeed. I've got also the same behaviour with `ng build -prod --watch`

Any ideas how to get the build right the first time?

*please note that I do not have any child routes/modules in my project and I don't have any other output to see what is causing this.*

**Update**: tested with child routes and I still get the same behaviour

**Update**: downgraded @angular libs to 2.4.0 from 4.0.0 and I still get the exact same behaviour, but with a different error message;

ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule

Comment: have you looked at this? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3841 are you using `export default` ? also what version of the cli are you on?

Comment: Yes, I did see the issue on github. However, I don't use an export default. I don't think that it would explain this behaviour because with the use of export default would always result in a failed build, don't you think?

Comment: hmmm, have you tried uninstalling the cli and reinstalling it? `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` then install it back. In your app, remove `node_modules` folder then `npm install`

Try `ng serve` again. Also, it might be worth trying to run your project's local cli instead of the global one. you can do this by running `npm start` whick essentially will call the `start` script in `scripts` in `package.json`

If that does not work, please post your router configs here

Comment: @Ahmed Not sure about what you want to see? I've got the default RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) in my AppModule

Comment: I'd like to see the appRoutes

Comment: I've got a lot of them, but they are all like this: export const clientRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "clients", component: ClientsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "clients/create", component: CreateClientComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }]; then in an other file i concat all the routes to call the forRoot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139510/discussion-between-gyocol-and-ahmed-musallam).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had multiple ts files for my routes and what I did was import all those routes in my app.routes and then concat them all together to call forRoot:

`export const appRoutes = xRoutes.concat(zRoutes)` etc

after putting all my routes in one single file/export const statement the error/weird build behaviour disappeared.

Comment: I get the same issue, but why does that happen? I need to add some properties to some of my routes, so I definitely want to setup multiple arrays first, manipulate some of them and concat them later. Do you know where the problem is here?

Answer (score 13):

I also ran into a similar issue with the Angular CLI v1.6.

In my case I was not using `.concat()` or any other kind of dynamic manipulation of the router definitions.

Rather I had a function in a data property of a route which was an anonymous arrow function. Changing this to a named exported function solved the issue for me.

Before:

```
 {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent,
    data: {
        breadcrumb: (data: any, params: any) => {
            let id = params['id'];
            return id === 'create' ? 'New Product' : data.product.ShortDescription;
        }
    }
}
```

After:

```
{
    path: ':id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: getBreadcrumb }
}

export function getBreadcrumb(data: any, params: any): string {
    let id = params['id'];
    return id === 'create' ? 'New Product' : data.product.ShortDescription;
}
```

Comment: I was using .concat and that was giving me problem. I ended up using the spread operator e.g. [...array1, ...array2] and that worked.

Answer (score 13):

I got this error due to double comma in routing as below

[image]

Comment: yes! Even I too had same error and that too because of this silly copy paste error! Angular 10

Answer (score 11):

In my case, [this answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4686#issuecomment-465045368) to a related Github issue fixed my error.

In case it gets deleted, the fix was changing this:

```js
export const ROUTES = MY_ROUTES.map(TO_ANGULAR_ROUTE)
```

to this:

```js
export const ROUTES = [];
ROUTES.push(...MY_ROUTES.map(TO_ANGULAR_ROUTE));
```

Comment: Aaaah this is it.. weird that we can't rest directly in the exported array

Answer (score 10):

This is likely due to some syntax error in your project, build with

`ng build --prod --aot`

To get a more detailed error message.

Comment: it was not syntax error though, but that way helped to understand what is the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after serving my app and resolved it by pressing Ctrl+s in a file that was not even in an edited/unsaved state. Now it compiles without the warning. However, to get it to compile *the first time* was something very odd.

Storing an object instance in a variable and setting that variable as my [lazyLoaded] route's `data` was unacceptable to the TS/NG compiler. However, instantiating the object directly on the route's `data` property was acceptable.

I'm well aware that none of the above makes any intuitive sense, whatsoever, but I hope this saves somebody the time it could take to find this on your own.

Answer (score 2):

**Angular CLI ERROR in Cannot load app.module**
This problem occurs when the inside routing file in some syntax error.
so please check your syntax inside routes array

Comment: This answer hase been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53030605/5468463, although it seems not to be the solution wrt the comment under. So why repeat?

Answer (score 1):

### Mocks, Components, and RouteGuards

Another thing to check is if you're mocking/stubbing any classes in for dummy-components on a route declaration. It seems it can happen for mocked RouteGuards as well.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness: I ran into this issue when creating routes from a list of related objects:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { EXAMPLES, Example } from './examples-list';

const routes = [
  ...EXAMPLES.map(toRoute), // this line produced the error
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

// `export`ing this function fixed the error
export function toRoute(ex: Example): Route {
  return {
    path: ex.path,
    component: ex.component,
    data: { title: ex.title }
  };
}
```

I had to `export` the function I was using in `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but my requirement was to have all the routes in a separate file. I solved it by simply exporting my Routes[] like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 // ... all my route objects
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **Angular CLI ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null**
> ```

This problem occurs when routing name is not followed camelCase naming standard. I was take `dsar-config` name for module, when I changed it into `dsarConfig` then I'm not getting any compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was coming because of same routing path added twice to load two different component as below

```
{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'pageone', pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
   path: 'pageone',
   component: PageOneComponent
},
{
   path: '',
   children: [
  ...['PageTwoPartOne', 'PageTwoPartTwo', 'PageTwoPartOneQuickReference'].map(path => ({
      path,
      component: PageTwoComponent
    }))
   ]
},
```

After correcting one of the path (path:''), it's worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

in my case I have faced it when tried to concat one routes array to another:

```
export const businesslogicState: Routes = BUSINESSLOGIC_ROUTES.concat(gamesRoutes);
```

each parts of concat were Route[]

changing one element array gamesRoutes to Route object itself didn't help, still getting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

[image describing the error][1]

I had the same error.. when i checked the routing, I was having 2 comas somewhere as shown in the image. deleting one solved it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEKFo.png