# Angular 4 - Routes - How to create a separate module for managing routes and use it in app.module.ts file

Tags: angular, routes

I am newbie in Angular, I want to implement the `routes` in separate component and import the same component in `app.module.ts` file. How do I import the routes component in `app.module.ts` file.

I was trying like:
**app.routes.ts**

```
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';

export class AppRoutes {
    getRoutes() {
        return [
            {
                path: 'users',
                component: UsersComponent
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

in **app.modules.ts**

```
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes.getRoutes())
  ],
  providers: [UsersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**I am getting error in here:**

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes.getRoutes())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should create a **separate module** for routing and add your router info in this module.

**like this:**

*`routing.module.ts` file structure*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './user/login/login.component'; //your component

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [
      RouterModule
   ] 
})
export class RoutingModule { };
```

import `RouterModule` and config your routs info then **export** your config (in export section of router module) for another module like `app.module`.

then **import and inject** your routing module to your base module `app.module`

**like this:**

*`app.module.ts` file structure*

```
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: this is helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, I feel, it is the right way to do this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AppRoutes is a class so you need to instanciate it before using it:

```
let appRoutes = new AppRoutes();
```

then

```
...
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes.getRoutes())
```

Comment: So I stumbled upon this question because I needed to export a separate file with routes to the routingModule. Your answer lead me to my solution, but although it seems like it could work, you may be left with an error `Cannot read property loadChildren of undefined`. This in turn could be solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113429/angular-cli-error-in-cannot-read-property-loadchildren-of-null/48205304#48205304