# There are no common properties with the "Route" type

Tags: angular

Const routes highlights in red and outputs the following error:

```
Type "({path: string; component: Route [];} | {path: string;
component: Route []; canActivate: (typeof ..." can not be assigned for
type "Route []".

Type "{path: string; component: Route [];} | {path: string; component:
Route []; canActivate: (typeof ..." can not be assigned to the "Route"
type.

The "{path: string; component: Route [];}" type can not be assigned to
the "Route" type.

The property types of the "component" are incompatible.

The "Route []" type can not be assigned for type "type <any>".


The "apply" property is not present in the type "Route []".
```

and so on...

How can I fix this?

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SignInRoutes } from '../layout/sign-in/index';
import { LayoutRoutes } from '../layout/index';

import { SignInComponent } from '../layout/sign-in/sign-in.component';

import { AuthGuard } from '../shared/guards/auth.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [

{ path: 'sign_in',   component: SignInRoutes },
{ path: 'layout',   component: LayoutRoutes, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: '**', component: SignInComponent }

];
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402318/angular-4-routes-how-to-create-a-separate-module-for-managing-routes-and-use/48402585#48402585

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar problem few days back while including routes for my help module. I was putting [] in two places like this:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path : 'help', component : HelpComponent
  }
];
```

and

```
RouterModule.forRoot([routes])
```

which means I was converting routes array to array again.

But when I removed the **[] (square brackets)** from **RouterModule.forRoot** then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are assigning Routes to component property which is not allowed. If you are trying to achieve nested routes then you should use children property. Please refer the tutorial for more [info](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Answer (score 0):

I have enclosed an example.

```
const recipesRoutes : Routes = [
    { path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: RecipeEditComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent },
    { path: ':id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  ] },
];
```

Hope this helps!!