# Cannot get Angular routing to work

Tags: angular

In my `AppModule`, I have the following (removing unnecessary code):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CompanyModule } from './main/content/company/company.module';
import { CustomersModule } from './main/content/company/customers/customers.module';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path        : 'company',
    loadChildren: './main/content/company/company.module#CompanyModule'
  },
  {
    path        : '**',
    redirectTo  : 'company/dashboards/default'
  }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true }),
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent,
        CompanyModule,
        CustomersModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

Then I have `CompanyModule`:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path        : 'products',
        loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule'
    },
    {
        path        : 'customers',
        loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports     : [
        FuseSharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class CompanyModule
{
}
```

And `CustomersModule` (`ProductsModule` is similar and not included here):

```
const routes = [
    {
        path        : 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#CustomersDashboardModule'
    },
    {
        path        : 'customer',
        loadChildren: './customer/customerdetail.module#CustomerDetailModule'
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class CustomersModule
{
}
```

The app starts and I'm presented with the component in `CompanyModule`. **I have a button which should take me to 'CustomersModule'**. When I click on it, I see that the `path` changes. However, I get an empty page.

The code on the `(click)` event is:

```
gotoCustomersDashboard()
{
    this.router.navigate(['company/customers/dashboard']);
}
```

The `CustomerDetailComponent`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerDetailService } from './customer.service';
import { CustomerDetailComponent } from './customer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path     : 'customer',
        component: CustomerDetailComponent,
        resolve  : {
            service: CustomerDetailService
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CustomerDetailComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    providers   : [
        CustomerDetailService
    ]
})
export class CustomerDetailModule
{
```

Router tracing shows that the Router Event 'NavigationEnded' and everything looks fine. There are also no other errors.

Is the above routing configuration missing something?

Comment: Are you using `export const CustomersModuleRoutes : ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);` and then import it in `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek No I don't have those. What should I add exactly and where?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402318/angular-4-routes-how-to-create-a-separate-module-for-managing-routes-and-use/48402585#48402585

Comment: @HasanFathi Isn't this similar to what I'm already doing?

Comment: Why are you adding  loading `{
        path        : 'customer',
        loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
    }` in `CustomerModule` again ? You are already loading it in `CompanyModule`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono please check you do not export your router info in modules

Comment: @HasanFathi : I think your suggestion is not valid here. He has implemented in diff way which seems correct

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono plase add complete code

Comment: @HasanFathi Updated the question with more code. However, apart from the `imports` (which I didn't include), there's no other code. They're simple modules to load the routes.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono please add `AppModule` code completly

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono you should import your modules in `AppModule`please add and test

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono please test and feedback me, thanks.

Comment: @HasanFathi Added to `AppModule` and updated my question. Still doesn't work. I still get a blank page. I also added the code that gets called on `(click)`.

Comment: Where is your `DashboardComponent`, I mean your component should be inside `declaration : [DashboardCompnent]` like this. No component is put into your `declaration` that's why page is showing blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click: `this.router.navigate(['company/customers/customer/customer']);`

Comment: Adding the components to the `declaration` results in this runtime error: Unexpected module 'CustomerComponent' declared by the module `AppModule`, Please add @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: Have you created any component that match the route inside your customer module?????

Comment: Yes. The customer module should load 2 further modules (customerdetail, customerdashboard) and these 2 modules have components. The customer module itself doesn't have a component though as none is needed.

Comment: Try this on button click: `this.router.navigate(['company/customers/customer/customer']);`

Comment: That works. Why do I need to add the extra `customer` path at the end?

Comment: Actually,  you have load URL till customer module further you have to set customerdetail module path which is again customer as you set

Comment: Appmodule(company)/companymodule(customers)/customermodule(customer)/customerdetailmodule(customer). Hope this will clear to you.