# Angular 06: ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null on compile

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I just recently upgraded my project to Angular 6 and ran into this issue.
**ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null**. This error occurs for the first time when I compile my project and when compiled again on updating other parts of the project, the error goes away.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113429/angular-cli-error-in-cannot-read-property-loadchildren-of-null), but to no success.

It was working properly earlier with Angular 5.

This is my RoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { adminRoutes } from '@ui/admin-module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
          ...adminRoutes,
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The problem is with the **adminRoutes** which when I'm removing, the compilation error goes away.

Please help me understand what is causing the issue? Also, let me know if there are more details I need to provide. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Providing the admin routes and module details.**

**Admin routes**

```
    import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { LayoutComponent } from './core';
import { designationRoutes } from './modules/designations';
import { organizationRoutes } from './modules/organizations';
import { rolesRoutes } from './modules/roles';
import { templateRoutes } from './modules/templates';
import { userRoutes } from './modules/users';

export const adminModuleRoutes: Routes = [
  ...rolesRoutes,
  ...userRoutes,
  ...designationRoutes,
  ...organizationRoutes,
  ...templateRoutes
];

export const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'roles' },
        ...adminModuleRoutes
    ]
  }
];
```

**Admin Module**

```
export class AdminModule {
  static forRoot(configProvider: Provider[]): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AdminModule,
      providers: [
        ...configProvider
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show your `adminRoutes` and `admin-module`.

Comment: @ritaj, just did that.

Answer (score 1):

Gather all your routes: `adminRoutes` and then `roleRoutes`, `userRoutes` etc. and put them in the same file.

The problem is, that when building the routes, Angular seems not to follow multiple-layer links. That's my guess based on the question you mentioned as well.

Comment: I did that. But the error still persists. I believe the Admin module structure needs refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it seems the issue is using Routes instead of Route[].  I'm guessing the spread operator and the typescript "export declare type Routes = Route[];" don't play well together.